# Briggs and Stratton Stalls after Sea Foam Treatment

Tags: fuel-system, stall, briggs-stratton

I have an older 2cyl 16hp Briggs and Stratton engine on my old garden tractor. I inherited it with my property purchase, so I have no idea how it's been maintained.

I put new gas in and changed the oil this spring and started working with it. It runs reasonably well but it was surging quite a bit, especially when it got warm. Also, it wouldn't idle down properly.

On the last refueling I dumped some Sea-Foam into the gas tank before filling up. Now, however, it seems that the RPMs are low when at full throttle and the tractor will stall out when I put it into gear. The tractor has a belt-drive transmission.

I'm thinking of starting with cleaning or replacing the spark plugs and possibly replacing the fuel filter.

Any thoughts/suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: How much Seafoam did you put into how much gad? It could be you've saturated you fuel with too much of it and now it's not running so well

Answer (score 2):

I think your plan to clean/replace the spark plugs and replace the fuel filter it a good idea.  I also suggest inspecting and cleaning the carburetor since sitting for even a few weeks with Ethanol-laced gasoline in it can cause corrosion and/or deposit build up that will cause exactly the symptoms you describe.

I have seen Sea-Foam and similar products partially liquify some of that goop so that it clogs the passages in the carb even more.

Comment: Cleaning the air filter would be a good choice as well.